# proc means output percentile statistics

Tags: sas, output

```
proc means data = data1 stackODSoutput MIN P10 P25 P50 P75 P90 MAX N NMISS SUM nolabels maxdec=3;
var var1 var2;
output out = output;
run;
```

From the generated report, I can get all percentile and SUM. but the output data just provide me basic statistics with N, MIN, MAX, MEAN and std.
How can I also output the percentile and sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `output` datasets in `proc means`, you need to specify which statistics you'd like within the `output` statement. Think of the `proc` statement as only controlling the visual output. Try this instead:

```
proc means data=sashelp.cars;
    var horsepower MPG_City MPG_Highway;
    output out=output 
        sum=
        mean=
        median=
        std=
        min=
        max=
        p10=
        p25=
        p75=
        p90=
        / autoname
    ;

run;
```

Note that none of the statistics have anything after the `=`. The `autoname` option is automatically naming the statistic variables.

To make it easier to read, we can change the format of the output table. The naming convention of all variables is `<variable>_<statistic>`. Knowing this, we can transpose the table, separate out the variable and statistics from the name, then re-transpose it into a nicer format.

```
proc transpose data=output out=output_transposed;
    var _NUMERIC_;
run;

data _want(index=(variable) );
    set output_transposed;

    Stat = scan(_NAME_, -1, '_');
    Variable = tranwrd(_NAME_, cats('_', Stat), '');

    keep Variable Stat COL1;

    rename COL1 = Value;
run; 

proc transpose data=_want out=want(drop=_NAME_);
    by variable;
    id stat;
    var Value;
run;
```

Comment: the output include all the information I need, but the format became very ugly. Everything squeezs into 1 line. That is variableA_Min, variable_B_min, variableA_sum, variableB_sum. Anyway to fix it? I wish I can get the default output format, or the format  in the report.